# Visual Studio Express 12 (2013) with CMake 3 and shared libraries provides LNK1104 errors

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, cmake, shared-libraries

I have the following CMakeLists.txt

```
project(testproject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

add_library(library lib.cpp)

add_executable(test.x main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test.x library)
```

If I build a project for visual studio with

```
cmake path\to\project
```

then open the solution in visual studio express 12 I have no problems.  However, if I build the project with

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON path\to\project
```

Then I get the following error in visual studio:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\library.lib'
```

which seems to be because, as per what I specified, visual studio built the file 'Debug\library.dll'

Everything works fine if I do a linux makefile build.

So...any idea why visual studio is still looking for the static lib?  Is this a cmake bug, or something I did?

I'm not very experienced at windows-side development, so I would appreciate any help you could give.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably this is because you are not "exporting" anything.

#### Example

If you create library `foo`:

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp foo.hpp)
```

CMake will provide `foo_EXPORTS` macro for you in case shared library is building:

```
cl /c ... /D foo_EXPORTS
```

You can use this macro to declare your functions, something like this:

```
// foo.hpp
#if defined(_WIN32) 
# if defined(foo_EXPORTS)
#  define FOO_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
# else
#  define FOO_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
# endif // Foo_EXPORTS
#else // _WIN32
# define FOO_EXPORT
#endif

FOO_EXPORT int foo();
```

#### Update

Header can be generated automatically using [GenerateExportHeader](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) module:

```
// foo.hpp
#include "foo_export.h" // foo_export.h is generated for you
FOO_EXPORT int foo();

# CMakeLists.txt
include(GenerateExportHeader) # include module with function `generate_export_header`
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}") # this is the default directory for generated header, i.e. location of generated file `${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/foo_export.h`

add_library(foo foo.cpp foo.hpp)
generate_export_header(foo) # create `foo_export.h`
```

Comment: See also: [The `GenerateExportHeader module`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late response...I kind of put this aside after I didn't get any responses.  It looks like this is exactly what I need to do :-)  Thanks for furthering my windows building knowledge!